# Hashcash proof of work bitcoin sha256

Tags: proof-of-work

I'm looking for a program or something to run from the terminal in mac.
That does the same thing as the program found here. http://www.blockchain-basics.com/HashPuzzle.html?nonce=221

What I'm looking for is the ability to check how many times a hash using the same hash- Noucing up has two leading zeros. I want to be able to list each hash for 20 hashing of two leading zeros.

Eg. "HI 183" hashed has two leading zeros
Eg. "HI 2121" hashed has two leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

This should produce identical output:

```
$ echo -n "HI 71592" | shasum -a 256
0000ca92719894f1444e485036aabed9f9223b6bb06928a3561567c821424a41
```